# Why I can't specify the italian language for the validation messages of the JQuery Validation Plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have some problem trying to add the internazionalization language support the the **JQuery Validation Plugin**, this one: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

So I have done the following operation.

I have this script that correctly validate my form:

```
                // VALIDAZIONE FORM DI RICERCA:
                $("#ricercaForm").validate({

                    lang: 'it',

                    rules : {

                        codiceMeccanografico : {
                            require_from_group : [ 1, ".requiredGroup1" ]
                        },

                        codiceRegione : {
                            require_from_group : [ 1, ".requiredGroup1" ]
                        }

                    }
                });
```

As you can see I have inserted the **lang: 'it',** to specify to use the italian language.

Then I have put the **messages_it.js** into this directory of my project: **\workspaceWIFI\WIFIPNSD\src\main\webapp\resources\js\jquery\localization**

The **messages_it.js** simply contain the definition of the error messages in italian language:

```
(function( factory ) {
    if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
        define( ["jquery", "../jquery.validate"], factory );
    } else {
        factory( jQuery );
    }
}(function( $ ) {

/*
 * Translated default messages for the jQuery validation plugin.
 * Locale: IT (Italian; Italiano)
 */
$.extend($.validator.messages, {
    required: "Campo obbligatorio",
    remote: "Controlla questo campo",
    email: "Inserisci un indirizzo email valido",
    url: "Inserisci un indirizzo web valido",
    date: "Inserisci una data valida",
    dateISO: "Inserisci una data valida (ISO)",
    number: "Inserisci un numero valido",
    digits: "Inserisci solo numeri",
    creditcard: "Inserisci un numero di carta di credito valido",
    equalTo: "Il valore non corrisponde",
    extension: "Inserisci un valore con un&apos;estensione valida",
    maxlength: $.validator.format("Non inserire pi&ugrave; di {0} caratteri"),
    minlength: $.validator.format("Inserisci almeno {0} caratteri"),
    rangelength: $.validator.format("Inserisci un valore compreso tra {0} e {1} caratteri"),
    range: $.validator.format("Inserisci un valore compreso tra {0} e {1}"),
    max: $.validator.format("Inserisci un valore minore o uguale a {0}"),
    min: $.validator.format("Inserisci un valore maggiore o uguale a {0}"),
    nifES: "Inserisci un NIF valido",
    nieES: "Inserisci un NIE valido",
    cifES: "Inserisci un CIF valido",
    currency: "Inserisci una valuta valida"
});

}));
```

Finally I have included this **messages_it.js** file into my page, infact when I open the page in the browser I have the related correct link to thsi javascript file.

The problem is that I still have the error messages in English language.

Why? What am I missing? How can I try to solve this issue?

Comment: is messages_it included after jquery.validate??

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option called `lang` for this plugin...

```
$("#ricercaForm").validate({
    lang: 'it',  // <- no such option
    ....
```

Please refer to [the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) for all available options.

---

After you include the plugin, simply include this...

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    required: "Campo obbligatorio",
    remote: "Controlla questo campo",
    email: "Inserisci un indirizzo email valido",
    url: "Inserisci un indirizzo web valido",
    date: "Inserisci una data valida",
    dateISO: "Inserisci una data valida (ISO)",
    number: "Inserisci un numero valido",
    digits: "Inserisci solo numeri",
    creditcard: "Inserisci un numero di carta di credito valido",
    equalTo: "Il valore non corrisponde",
    extension: "Inserisci un valore con un&apos;estensione valida",
    maxlength: $.validator.format("Non inserire pi&ugrave; di {0} caratteri"),
    minlength: $.validator.format("Inserisci almeno {0} caratteri"),
    rangelength: $.validator.format("Inserisci un valore compreso tra {0} e {1} caratteri"),
    range: $.validator.format("Inserisci un valore compreso tra {0} e {1}"),
    max: $.validator.format("Inserisci un valore minore o uguale a {0}"),
    min: $.validator.format("Inserisci un valore maggiore o uguale a {0}"),
    nifES: "Inserisci un NIF valido",
    nieES: "Inserisci un NIE valido",
    cifES: "Inserisci un CIF valido",
    currency: "Inserisci una valuta valida"
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/28zrmgmb/**